# Biostats. Longitudinal data clustering with missing data and Frechet distance

Tags: time-series, missing-data, biostatistics, distance, clinical-trials

I am trying to cluster individuals that underwent a clinical challenge, using longitudinal data. The individual were inoculated viruses. I want clusters with individuals whose body response over time are similar.

I have 2 variables : body temperature (daily) and virus DNA count (obtained by bleeding every 2 or 3 days)

I would like to use Frechet's distance (but any suggestion for an alternative method will be appreciated !) to get a distance matrix, and then plug it into some hierarchical clustering algorithm. My problem comes from the structure of the data. A picture is worth 10000 words :

[image: a "X" means a measurement]

I have no problem to compute separately Frechet's distance on BT and DNA. However, I cannot compute the intuitive $R^{2}$ Frechet's distance because I have missing data. 
What would you recommend to me ? 
-Infer the data ? Renormalize each variable *a priori* ? Renormalize the distance matrices *a posteriori* and then combine them using sum or max ?...

Thank you for your thoughts,

Alex